# Only detect contours within a square

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Hello I have a code which draws me the outlines of shapes/objects which have 3 or 4 vertices. So far everything works. But now I want that only shapes/objects are recognized, which are in a square. I wanted to solve it in such a way that I create a square or a picture, in which a square is represented, with `cv2.imread` read and then with `cv2.matchShapes` check, how much the recognized contour agrees with the contour of the square. And if this match is good enough, corresponding objects/shapes within this square should be recognized.
Following is the code I have written so far:

```py
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
from graphics import *


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)

rect = cv2.imread("Rectangle.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rect, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rectcontour, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


while True:
     _ , img = cam.read()
     img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
     gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     #edges = cv2.Canny(gray1, 250, 300)
     _ , binary1 = cv2.threshold(gray1, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
     inverted_binary1 = ~binary1
     contours1, _ = cv2.findContours(inverted_binary1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

     a = 0
     for a in contours1:
          x = cv2.matchShapes(contours1[a], rectcontour[0], cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
          print(x)
          a = a + 1

     for contour in contours1:
          area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
          if  area > 100 and area < 20000:
               approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.06 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
               print(len(approx))

               if 2 < len(approx)  < 5:
                    moment = cv2.moments(contour)
                    cx = int(moment['m10'] / moment['m00'])
                    cy = int(moment['m01'] / moment['m00'])
                    #print(x, y)
                    print(cx, cy)
                    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
                    n = approx.ravel()
                    print(n)
                    i = 0
                    for j in n:
                         if (i % 2 == 0):
                              x = n[i]
                              y = n[i + 1]

                              # String containing the co-ordinates.
                              string = str(x) + " " + str(y)


                              if (i == 0):
                                   # text on topmost co-ordinate.
                                   cv2.putText(img, string, (x, y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (255, 0, 0))
                              else:
                                   # text on remaining co-ordinates.
                                   cv2.putText(img, string, (x, y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0))
                         i = i + 1




     cv2.imshow("schwarz, weiß", inverted_binary1)
     cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)

     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
          break
```

At the moment I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\Opencv\test3.py", line 27, in <module>
    x = cv2.matchShapes(contours1[a], rectcontour[0], cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

And I dont exactly know how I can fix that.

The square image I am using:
[image]

And another Picture of the shape I actually want to detect:
[image]